# Can grapgviz be embeded into html page and dynamically corresponde to user's click?

Tags: graphviz

I am now looking for a drawing tools which is used in my website.This tool can draw relationship diagram and can correspond to user's click.For example ,this graph shows the partnership of employees in a company , each node of the graph represents a employee. When we left click on one of the nodes of the graph , the page will show  another figure,containing the details of this employee.
Some one recommend graphviz, but it seems that graphviz can only draw pre-defined picture and cannot correspond to user's input.
So , any ideas or recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

You could use GraphViz to compute positions of nodes on the backend and send them back to the browser, so technically it could react to the user's input. A more natural approach would seem to me to do these computations directly in the browser, though, and I believe that's what you mean when you say react to users' input. You might want to check out http://d3js.org